# VB.Net Adding items to a Reply Keyboard for Telegram.bot

Tags: c#, vb.net, telegram-bot, ienumerable

I am using VB.Net (VS2019) and the [Telegram.bot](https://github.com/Eptagone/Telegram.BotAPI/blob/main/src/Telegram.BotAPI.Examples/ReplyKeyboardMarkup%2001/readme.md) API. In the C# sample, they show how to add items to the replykeyboard. I'm afraid I don't understand the `IEnumerable` concept at all, but I have managed to translate the C# to working VB.Net code anyway.

This is the code:
C#

```
 if (update.Message.Text.Contains("/reply"))
    {
      var keyboard = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup
      {
       Keyboard = new KeyboardButton[][]{
                  new KeyboardButton[]{
                  new KeyboardButton("Button 1"), //column 1 row 1
                  new KeyboardButton("Button 2") //column 1 row 2
                },// column 1
                  new KeyboardButton[]{
                  new KeyboardButton("Button 3") //col 2 row 1
                } // column 2
       },
       ResizeKeyboard = true
    }; ;
   bot.SendMessage(update.Message.Chat.Id, "new keyboard", replyMarkup: keyboard);
}
```

The VB Code is

```
If update.Message.Text.Contains("/reply") Then
    Dim keyboard = New ReplyKeyboardMarkup With {
        .Keyboard = New KeyboardButton()() {New KeyboardButton() {New KeyboardButton("Button 1"), New KeyboardButton("Button 2")}, New KeyboardButton() {New KeyboardButton("Button 3")}},
        .ResizeKeyboard = True
    }
    bot.SendMessage(update.Message.Chat.Id, "new keyboard", replyMarkup:=keyboard)
End If
```

My question is how I can update that on the fly?
I an reading a table from sqlite and I want to create the buttons to hold the rowids of the records..
So I have

```
 mySQL = "select * from products;"
 Dim cs As String = "URI=file:" & DBName
Using con As New SQLiteConnection(cs)
   con.Open()
   Dim dr As SQLiteDataReader
   Using DBcmd As New SQLiteCommand(con)
       DBcmd.CommandText = mySQL
       dr = DBcmd.ExecuteReader()
       While dr.Read()
           MsgText &= String.Format("Code: *{0}* [{1}]({3}), Price: ${2}", dr("Code"), Replace(dr("ProdName"), "-", " "), dr("Price"), dr("ProdURL")) & vbCrLf
       End While
    End Using
    con.Close()
End Using
```

In that loop I would like to build the keyboard adding one button for each occurrence of the  `dr("code")` as the text of the button.

Help please?

Comment: `IEnumerable(Of T)` is nothing more or less than a sequence of `T` that can be iterated over each element.  Anything that can provide elements in a sequence satisfies the interface.  (Linq provides a functional programming interface for manipulating the sequences provided by implementations of `IEnumerable`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to create a `List(Of KeyboardButton())`, i.e. a generic `List` of `KeyboardButton` arrays. You can read from your data reader in a loop, create an array of `KeyboardButton` for the current record and add it to the `List`. Finally, call `ToArray` on the `List` to get a jagged array of `KeyboardButton` that you can assign to the `Keyboard` property. E.g.

```vb
Dim keyboardButtons As New List(Of KeyboardButton())

While dr.Read()
    keyboard.Add({New KeyboardButton(dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("Code")))})
End While

Dim keyboard As New ReplyKeyboardMarkup With {.Keyboard = keyboardButtons.ToArray()}
```

Comment: Thank you. That works. Had to change the one line:
to 
 keyboardButtons.Add({New KeyboardButton("/pd " & dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("Code")))})

Comment: You could make that simpler like so: `keyboard.Add({New KeyboardButton($"/pd {dr("Code")}")})`.